# limit() method in laravel's query builder returns error

Tags: php, laravel, database, backend, query-builder

Code of query:

```
$data = DB::connection('oracle')
    ->table('m.rsc_claim as rc')
    ->select('rc.num as order_number',
        'rld.name as reason_claim',
        'rc.work_bdate as start_date',
        'rc.address_name as address_name'
    )
    ->leftJoin('m.rsc_lst_declaration as rld', 'rld.id', 'rc.declaration_id')
    ->where('user_id', $userId)
    ->latest('rc.bdate')
    ->first();
```

But that's give me error "json_decode(): Argument #1 ($json) must be of type string, stdClass given"

The most amazing thing is that there are no errors using limit(1) and give() instead of first().

Just in case I checked the type $userId, it is a string

Comment: [`first()`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#retrieving-a-single-row-column-from-a-table) returns a single object, while [`limit(1)->get()`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#retrieving-all-rows-from-a-table) returns a collection with a single item. There's nothing about json here, so I can't tell you what's wrong with that.

Comment: You seem to be using single quotes and the occasional backtick in that select! Is that correctly coded??

Comment: Please, copy/paste code from what you are ACTUALLY RUNNING. We cannot debug errors in code you are NOT RUNNING

Comment: @RiggsFolly Right, I made a mistake when copying and editing the code when I asked the question. Thanks for the clarification. Already edited

Comment: @aynber, It is clear that one method returns a collection and the other object. But how does this affect the fact that the error occurs exactly when calling the one that returns the object?

Comment: The error is related to `json_decode`, which is not in your code here. Can you provide the full function as well as the full error message (with stack trace if you can)?

Comment: The error comes from postman, all there is text "errorMessage": "json_decode(): Argument #1 ($json) must be of type string, stdClass given"

Comment: The error was received in Postman, but the error comes from Laravel. Check your Laravel logs in `storage/logs` for the trace and the full error message with file and line numbers

Comment: Hmm, when I was fresh, the error was really in the fact that first() returns a single object, while limit(1)->get() returns a collection with a single item. Thank you for your time and answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was that the `first()` method returns a ready object, while the `limit(1)->get()` methods return a collection. Then code worked exactly with the collection, hence the error